# Java 8 Array Stream Filter

Tags: java, filter, java-8, java-stream

I have one simple array with custom object and want to filter with java 8 stream.

```
    A[] aArray = new A[3];

    A a1 = new A();
    a1.setaId(1);
    a1.setaName("AName1");

    B b1 = new B();
    b1.setbId(1);
    b1.setbName("BName1");

    a1.setB(b1);
    aArray[0] = a1;

    A a2 = new A();
    a2.setaId(2);
    a2.setaName("AName2");

    B b2 = new B();
    b2.setbId(2);
    b2.setbName("BName2");

    a2.setB(b2);
    aArray[1] = a2;
```

Can you please suggest how can I go for filter stream on array NOT ON arrayList

Basically I want to filter with only "BName2" value.

Comment: Your array size should be 2. So the declaration should be changed like: `A[] aArray = new A[2];`

Comment: As an aside define yourself some good constructors so you may do just `A[] aArray = new A[] { new A(1, "AName1", new B(1, "BName1")), new A(2, "AName2", new B(2, "BName2")), null };`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are storing unique element in the array then you can use following approach

**If the object is Unique**

```
A aWithValidString = Arrays.stream(aArray)
    .filter(a -> "BName2".equals(a.getB().getbName()))
    .finAny().orElse(null);
```

**If you have multiple Objects in Array with "Bname2" string you can use Below code**

```
List<A> filteredObject = Arrays.stream(aArray)
    .filter(a -> "BName2".equals(a.getB().getbName()))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

And Iterate List

Comment: Calling `Optional.get` is always a mistake.

Comment: @BoristheSpider Corrected, Thanks :)

Comment: `.orElse(null)` always gives me depression... With `Optional` why do you even want to use `null`? You can just return `Optional` and that all - no sense to mapping it to null